# React decorators: annotating a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Is it possible to annotate a function with a custom annotation? How to implement the same? For Example-

```
@customAnnotation
const check = (role, action) => {

 ///...do Something..

};
```

Answer (score 0):

if your function is inside some class you can use  **Class Method Decorator**. [Here](https://itnext.io/a-minimal-guide-to-ecmascript-decorators-55b70338215e) many examples given how it should be done. You can also decorate field of class using **Class Instance Field Decorator**.